# Hightlight cells that DO NOT falls within a percentage range

Tags: google-sheets, range, google-sheets-formula, percentage, conditional-formatting

I am trying to highlight the cells in column L that DO NOT fall within a certain percentage : between -30% of J2 and +30% of  J2

basically, if the value in L2 is NOT within a 30% range (under or over) the value in J2, Then turn the row in RED

I tried this =and(L2>=0.9*J2,L2>=1.1*J2) in Conditional formatting, but  it doesn't seem to be working

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=NOT((L2>=-30%)*(L2<=30%))
```

[image]